# How to perform partial matches when filtering Slickgrid using column-level headers?

Tags: slickgrid

When using a fixed header row to implement column-level filters, how can I return cells with a partial match?

ie: 
search term: "omato"

returns: automator, tomato etc.

Answer (score 6):

Under MyFilter in the example replace this loop...

```
for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
    if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
        var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
        if (item[c.field] != columnFilters[columnId]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

with this..

```
for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
    if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
        var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
        if (item[c.field].indexOf(columnFilters[columnId]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Seems so obvious now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the coffeescript code I use to acheive this:

```
filterGrid = (item) ->
    return true unless hasFilter
    grid.setSelectedRows([])
    columns = grid.getColumns()
    for columnId, filter of columnFilters
        if filter? 
            column = columns[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)]
            field = item[column.field]
            return false unless (field? && field.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1) 
    return true
```

The line `grid.setSelectedRows([])` just clears any selected rows before applying the filter. If you don't do this then the selected rows you see on-screen do not match the underlying selected rows.

More importantly the `return true unless hasFilter` line prevents any filtering work whilst the grid is loading, unless the user has actually typed into one of the boxes. I have found that this makes quite a difference to the performance of the grid when loading large datasets in batches of JSON data over http.

Here is the input box handler that sets the `hasFilter` flag:

```
$(grid.getHeaderRow()).delegate(':input', 'change keyup', (e) ->
    columnId = $(this).data('columnId')
    if columnId?
        columnFilters[columnId] = $.trim($(this).val())
        hasFilter = true
        dataView.refresh()
)
```