# How to search for partial matches in numbers using SlickGrid header row?

Tags: header, match, partial, slickgrid

I'm trying to perform partial matches in the header row example for SlickGrid.

I used the answer here:
[How to perform partial matches when filtering Slickgrid using column-level headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576844/how-to-perform-partial-matches-when-filtering-slickgrid-using-column-level-heade)

Which does do partial matches on text but will not do partial matches on numbers. Does anyone know how to do partial matches on both? Some of my columns have text and some have numbers and I want to be able to filter by each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your numbers as text in the grid data. Then this method should work for numbers as well. Same applies to boolean and dates as well.

If you want to keep using numbers though, you could check for the variable type in your filter using the `typeof` function and adding a new condition to handle number matches.

Comment: Got it. I've used a workaround by adding "" before the number and then appending the number with +. I'll add a type filter hopefully.